# What type of analysis would be apt here?

Tags: regression, repeated-measures

I want to run an analysis looking at the changes of mean insomnia scores over time. I want to look at how these scores change (decrease/increase) over 3 different time points, however, the time points are age (so a continuous dv). I was wondering what type of analysis I would need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need a method that allows you to analyze your data while accounting for the fact that measurements of insomnia are 'nested' within individuals (i.e. observations are clustered). Linear Mixed Models allow you to do this.The fact that time is coded as continuous age is not a problem for these models as they can handle data that are not equally spaced in time.

Other terms that are used to refer to the same sort of models are Hierarchical Linear Models, Multilevel Models and Random Effects Models. There is much more to say about LMMs, but it is probably best to consult a textbook (e.g., multilevel analyses by Snijders & Bosker) to gain a more complete picture of the technique.

As a side note: As you are interested in change of insomnia scores over time, the model would take the form of a regression model with insomnia as your dependent variable and time as independent variable. So time would not be your 'dv' as you stated in your question.